# What is a simple way to keep a java network socket alive?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I am trying to write a small program to open a socket to a minecraft server so I can interact with it over its remote console.

I get the basics on how to work with Java sockets but I cannot figure out a simple way to keep the socket running in the background while I do work such as taking user input from the console or reading a config file.

Some of the example I had looked at involved using threads and creating a network thread just for keeping the socket connected to the server.

When I try to get a thread to work the program runs but it immediately switches to thread 1 (the one I made) and then it won't print my test lines since thread 0 has been suspended is being told to wait.

The issue I really don't fully understand threading so I am at a bit of a loss with that. But I cannot figure out a way to make something simple. Any ideas?

Here is the code I have done so far, it's not much but maybe it will help.

```
package com.solignis.rcon;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Connection extends Thread {

    private InetSocketAddress serverAddress;
    private int timeout;

    private Socket socket;

    public Connection(String par1, int par2) {
        serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress(par1, par2);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        socket = new Socket();

        try {
            socket.connect(serverAddress, timeout);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(socket.isConnected()) {

        }
    }

    public void connect() {
        this.run();
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverAddress.toString());

        if(socket.isConnected()){
            System.out.println("Connection established");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Connection failed");
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        this.notify();

        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define 'keep the socket running in the background', 'keeping the socket open', etc. The socket remains open until you close it. Period.

Comment: @EJP Or the remote host closes it...

Comment: @CPUTerminator No. That closes the *connection.* The socket remains open. Precision please.

Comment: @EJP Ehh... Okay... But I think OP means keep a socket **connected** in this case, rather than just open. Nevertheless, yes, only unless you close the socket it will remain open like EJP said, but that doesn't mean it'll stay connected. A remote host can **disconnect** you.

Comment: @CPUTerminator I am commenting on what he actually *said.* I'm not interested in speculating on what he might have meant.

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant. I want to keep the connection to the server alive. I changed my post to reflect that.

Comment: Once you connect the socket, it will stay open (Unless you explicitly close it or utilize java's try-with resource [and the block ends]). Whether it will stay connected or not depends on if the remote host has any mechanism of disconnecting unresponsive clients or if it has set a communications timeout. No loops or any operations are required to keep it open.

Comment: Your code is complete nonsense. The loop on `while (socket.isConnected())` is literally a waste of time, as well as smoking the CPU, as well as stealing cycles from other threads. You're using `wait()` and `notify()` to no apparent purpose. I suggest you find a networking tutorial, e.g. the [Custom Networking trail of the Oracle Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/).

Comment: @EJP I was afraid of that, like I said I was trying to get anything to work. I resorted to making a frankenstein of code based on a handful of examples I had found.

Comment: In addition to Networking I suggest you look up on how Threading works... Its not a hard concept to grasp and is very very useful...

Answer (score 0):

Because  of the method end of run and no reference to the client socket,  the socket will be closed.I suggest you start a thread to keep writing stream to the server,and another thread to keep reading stream from the server.The code like:

```
class ReadThread extends Thread {

    private Socket s ;

    public ReadThread (Socket s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
                //read stream from the server
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }


class WriteThread extends Thread {
     //Like the read thread,keep a while(true) loop writing to the server
}


main(){
    Socket s=new Socket(host,pot);
    new WriteThread(s).start();
    new ReadThread(s).start();
}
```

Comment: The socket will not be closed at the end of the run() method, if that's what you're trying to say. It is an instance variable, so there is indeed a reference to it, so it will persist until explicitly closed or garbage-collected. -1

Comment: yeah,it's my mistake in comprehension.It will be garbage collected,not closed

Comment: It will be garbage collected when and if the `Connection` object is collected, and not before. It will be closed when that occurs, if ever.